# How best to approach key-value store for a collection of PyObjects that won't fit into memory?

Tags: dictionary, julia

I've got a long-running computation where the rate limiting step is generating individual intermediate computations of (rotations of) Spherical Harmonic coefficients using the Python package SHTools. I'm driving the rest of the computation using Julia and Distributed (on a SMP workstation, not a cluster).

In principal, if the results were simple Floats (or other bits types) SharedArrays.jl would do the trick. But, my values are PyObjects, not bits types.

I've looked at JuliaDB.jl (in memory only) and MMap.jl (bits types only).

Is there something obscure that looks like a memory mapped Dict, where I could store on a NVMe?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can used `SharedArrays.jl` to store Python objects and share it among workers. This is just slightly more complicated and some overhead is involved.

For simplicity let us consider this networkx graph:

```
using PyCall
nx = pyimport("networkx") # requires using Conda;Conda.add("networkx")
g =  nx.random_tree(10) 
# PyObject <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x0000000002267790>
```

What we can do is to serialize it into memory and share among processes. Let us start with the distributed cluster setup.

```
using Distributed, SharedArrays, PyCall, Serialization
Distributed.addprocs(2)
@everywhere using Distributed, SharedArrays, PyCall, Serialization

const data = SharedVector(Vector{UInt8}(undef, 1000))
@everywhere nx = pyimport("networkx") # all proceses need to have the Python library loaded otherwise they would fail!
```

Now let us store the Python object in the `SharedArray`. Of course it will not be as efficient as using bit types and hey this is a Python object not Julia object.

```
b = IOBuffer()
serialize(b, g)
seekstart(b)
bbytes = readavailable(b)
(@view data[1:8]) .= reinterpret(UInt8, [length(bbytes)])
(@view data[9:8+length(bbytes)]) .= bbytes
```

As you can see the first 8 bytes of `data` now holds the info about object size and the other bytes hold the object itself.
Since it is a `SharedArray` the Python object can be read by each worker in the cluster:

```
julia> @sync @distributed for i in 1:2
           mysize = reinterpret(Int, view(data,1:8))[1]
           g2 = deserialize(IOBuffer(collect(view(data,9:8+mysize))))
           println("I am worker $(myid()) and I got graph $g2 that has nodes $(g2.nodes)")
       end

      From worker 2:    I am worker 2 and I got graph PyObject <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x0000000032240AF0> that has nodes PyObject NodeView((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
      From worker 3:    I am worker 3 and I got graph PyObject <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x0000000032640AF0> that has nodes PyObject NodeView((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
Task (done) @0x0000000017596290
```

Hope that helps you in sharing a Python object among many workers.

Comment: Very interesting. I will definitely try this approach, and upvote/accept as answer if I can make it work!  
Your approach also omits the necessity of my needing to distribute the answers from the head node. I like it!

Comment: remember to load all Python modules on each worker - otherwise it may crash ugly! Also there are structures that cannot be send across processes such as ones holding an open file descriptor.